Assuming the conclusion while trying to prove an inequality
I am trying to prove the following inequality:
$$ \ln{\frac{2n} {n+1}} \lt \ln{\frac{2n+2} {n+2}} $$ for any $$n \gt 0$$
I started with the above statement, took antilog on both sides and rearranged the expressions to arrive at
$$(n^2 + 2n) \lt (n^2 + 2n) +1$$
Since the above statement is true, therefore my original statement must be true. But isn't starting the solution with the inequality that I am trying to prove assuming the conclusion?
How else could this statement be proved? Any help is appreciated.

Well, you need to observe that, for $x,6>0$, we have $\ln x< \ln y \iff x<y$ to justify "taking anti-logs of both sides".

Typically you'll start with the expression you want to prove then work backwards until you find something you know to be true. Once you've done that you'll reverse the steps to create the proof beginning with the true statement to arrive at the expression.

You proved that $p\implies q$ and that $q$ is true. This does not imply that $p$ is also true. To prove that $p$ is true, you must prove that $q \implies p$ and that $q$ is true.

It's a bit of subtle point, but no, you are not assuming the conclusion. You do indeed start by assuming that the inequality is true, and from there you proceed via legal operations to another statement (which in this case is the inequality $n^2+2n\lt n^2+2n+1$), which you are able to easily verify by considering its domain. Since it it is only true iff the original statement is, it being true implies that the original statement is also true. The conclusion however is not technically that "the original statement is true" (though it's phrased that way in practice); rather, it's that "our assumption that the original statement is true, is true". Again, I want to emphasize that this is a subtle point and in practice you need not worry about it. The important part is that you start with a statement you wish to verify and proceed legally to another statement that is easier to verify, which are connected via a bidirectional implication.
Edited Answer
Upon further reflection, I don't agree with the logic in my initial answer. It is still true that you're not assuming the conclusion here, but not for the reason I first stated. Rather, you begin with the statement you wish to prove and then show that its truth depends on very precise conditions. It is the proof that these conditions apply upon which the ultimate proof rests. At no stage are you assuming anything at all; the conditions may apply or they may not.
For clarity's sake I will go through a quick proof now, which depends upon the following facts:
Fact 1: if a function $f(x)$ is continuous and bijective, then $f(x)$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing
Fact 2: the function $f(x)=\operatorname{ln}x$ is continuous and bijective
Fact 3: for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{n+1}\lt \frac{1}{n}$
Proof:
Taken together, facts 1 and 2 imply that $\operatorname{ln}x$ is a strictly increasing function; that is, for all $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}^+$, if $x_1\lt x_2$ then $\operatorname{ln}x_1\lt \operatorname{ln}x_2$. Thus to prove the original inequality amounts to proving the inequality $\frac{2n}{n+1}\lt \frac{2n+2}{n+2}$.
Using polynomial division, the term on the left can be shown to equal $2-\frac{2}{n+1}$; similarly, the term on the right is equal to $2-\frac{2}{n+2}$. We therefore have the inequality $2-\frac{2}{n+1}\lt 2-\frac{2}{n+2}$. Of course we may cancel the $2$ on both sides, leaving us with $-\frac{2}{n+1}\lt -\frac{2}{n+2}$. Multiplying both sides by $-1$ reverses this inequality, so we now have $\frac{2}{n+2}\lt \frac{2}{n+1}$. Cancelling the common factor of $2$ yields $\frac{1}{n+2}\lt \frac{1}{n+1}$. But this is always true by virtue of fact 3, thus the claim is proved.
What's going on here?
The original statement to be proved is that which you gave, of course. The definition of the natural logarithm as a strictly increasing function allows us to consider the inequality of the arguments (which is the condition I mentioned earlier) instead of the inequality of the values of the function itself. Standard algebraic manipulations and fact 3 show that this inequality holds for any value of $n$. Since the original inequality is true if and only if the inequality of the arguments is true, and we were able to prove the inequality of arguments, it must be that the original statement was true. At no stage was any assumption made; it may well have turned out that the inequality of arguments was not true, in which case our conclusion would have been negative.
Hope this helps!

You can build a valid argument without assuming the conclusion, by reversing the steps in your original deduction. Each of the steps has an equivalence arrow pointing both ways, so reversing the steps does not affect their validity.
If $n>0$ then dividing both sides of the last inequality by the positive number $(n+1)(n+2)$ preserves the order, i.e., the "less than" relationship between both sides of the inequality. So does taking the logarithm of both sides in the final step (provided the arguments are positive, which they are).

could you please elaborate? what is meant by preserving the order and how it relates to not assuming the conclusion?

Ok added an introductory paragraph

There is the well known result for positive numbers $\frac ab<\frac cd\implies \frac ab<\frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac cd$
We have trivially $\frac{2n}{n+1}<2$ and since $\ln(\cdot)$ is an increasing function, the result is a direct consequence.

$\frac{2n}{n+1}<\frac 21\implies\frac{2n}{n+1}<\frac{2n+2}{n+2}\implies\ln\Big(\frac{2n}{n+1}\Big)<\ln\Big(\frac{2n+2}{n+2}\Big)$


Another way
$$\ln{\frac{2n} {n+1}} \lt \ln{\frac{2n+2} {n+2}} \iff \ln{\frac{2n+2} {n+2}}-\ln{\frac{2n} {n+1}}\gt 0 \iff \ln{\frac{(2n+2)(n+1)} {2n(n+2)}}\gt 0 $$
which requires
$${\frac{(2n+2)(n+1)} {2n(n+2)}}\gt 1 $$

The way you have obtained the inequality
$$\ln A\lt \ln B \iff e^{\ln A}\lt e^{\ln B} \iff A\lt B$$
is fine because $e^x$ is a strictly increasing function, more simply since also $\log x$ is a strictly increasing function we can conclude directly that
$$\ln A\lt \ln B \iff  A\lt B$$
assuming that $A,B>0$.

Another way.
Consider over the reals the function
$$f(n)= \log \left(\frac{2 n+2}{n+2}\right)-\log \left(\frac{2
   n}{n+1}\right)$$
$$f'(n)=-\frac{2}{n (n+1) (n+2)}$$ is always negative.
Moreover, there is no solution for $f(n)=0$ and finally, for large $n$
$$f(n)=\frac 1{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3} \right)$$

Since $n>0$,
$$
n+2>n+1\implies\frac{1}{n+1}>\frac{1}{n+2}
$$
and so,
$$
\frac{-2}{n+1}<\frac{-2}{n+2}\implies2-\frac{2}{n+1}<2-\frac{2}{n+2}
$$
which means,
$$
\frac{2n}{n+1}<\frac{2n+2}{n+2}
$$
Now, as $lnx$ is an increasing function, we have
$$
ln(\frac{2n}{n+1})<ln(\frac{2n+2}{n+2})
$$
I hope that this helps you.
